# Problems StoryBoard Too Late (Flip Navigation) (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, navigation, storyboard, flip

my problem is I have a Silverlight application with flip navigation which is composed of two a storyboard that rotates the page and To = 90 ,From = 0 and the other from = -90 To = 0, the problem is that the second page is more loaded with many components as an image button, calendar, then when you run it the first storyboard done well, but to make and execute immediately completed the second this takes too long to start/begin and this makes it look bad the effect of flip navigation .

help please, thx ..